# How to deploy the node.js application on server with different node version

Tags: node.js, deployment, webdeploy

I want to deploy my `node app` on server. but when I upload the node app to our server and then add `node.js` instalation then It is not opening the file. the index.js file is

```
const connectToDb = require("./DBconfig");
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');

connectToDb();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT | 5000;
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
connectToDb();

app.use( '/api/user' ,require('./routes/user') );
app.use( '/api/post' ,require('./routes/post') );

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('The site is start now')
})

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  const path = require("path");
  app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client','build','index.html'))
  })
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The node version in my local machine is `v16.14.0` but the node version that the NameCheap is given is `v14.18.3`

the node installation in Namecheap that I configure is [the installation of node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL97f.png)

the error message is triggered, when I hit the URL of API [API's URL](https://api.yourguide.pk/), is [the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CP5V.png). I am unable to find the solution to solve this problem. I read some articles in which the writer tells that this type of error occurs when we use the different node versions in the local machine and on the server machine but I can't do anything because I restrict to use of the `v14.18.3` on the server-side but I used the `v16.14.0` in my local machine. can anyone tell me the solution to solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

nvm is another useful tool that can help you to control the node version itself, you can use nvm commands to upgrade the node version quite easily.

```
nvm install <version-number>
nvm use 0.10
```

**using `nvm use -nodeversion` you can switch your node js version to your server node js version.**

Answer (score 0):

`webi` is also a great tool. I recommend completely uninstalling node and installing it fresh with `webi`.

```bash
# this will install node and the webi cli
# Linux/Mac
curl -sS https://webinstall.dev/node | bash

# Windows
curl.exe -A "MS" https://webinstall.dev/node | powershell

# then you can run the following to switch versions
webi node@14
```

See https://webinstall.dev/node/ for more info.